# Model Deforms when i Try To Pose It

Tags: rigging, surface-deform

I linked the bones to the model and when i tried to pose it the model turns bigger and wider

(normal model)

[image: (example image of the normal model)]

(deformed model)

[image]

I tried to change weights manually but that don't work. I'm new with rigging.

Comment: Did you apply the Scale and Rotation to your object before parenting the rig to it?

Answer (score 1):

As John says, you've stretched your armature in *Object* mode, now you need to apply the scale in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)